# Am I allowed to use an apple device from placeit.net with an app screenshot on Twitter?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I've built an iOS 8 app and I'm not 100% sure if I'm allowed to use a photo of an iPhone 5s running my app as a timeline picture on Facebook and Twitter (support pages)? The device will only be visible from the front, hence leaving the Apple logo hidden.

Thank you!
Erik

Comment: Is it showing Apple logo ?

Comment: @Buscar웃SD nope, sorry for the short question - pushed submit a little too soon and didn't see the edit button. It's only going to show the front side of the device

Comment: If there is not Apple logo on it then it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8909421/3290977):

> You will get lots of free iPhone 4s images from internet. There are
>   lot of sites which provides freebies for designers here is a link
>
> 365psd.com www.pixeden.com
>
> BR, Hari

If you are part of the apple developer program you can access the marketing section and get the iphone images that you are able to use.

Hope it helps.